# Redirecting to 404 component without changing URL in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm making a universal redux app where the user is redirected to a 404 route if he asks for a non-existing url, but I have [**this problem**](http://i.imgur.com/tXFDO4V.gifv) where if you click the back button it doesn't let you go back.

Is there a way to redirect to a 404 route without changing the url?

Here's how my routes look like:

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={MainPage} />
        <Route path="venues/:venueName" component={VenueContainer} />
        <Route path="404" component={NotFound} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Route>
);
```

Calling this redux action to redirect:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

export default function redirect404() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(push('/404'));
    };
}
```

What I have right now works but I can see some user-experience frustration coming out of it.

EDIT: I think the issue is arising from the routes with params, such as:
`<Route path="venues/:venueName" component={VenueContainer} />`. 
React-router sees a match and doesn't redirect to:
`<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />`.

I'm requesting data from an external API and if there is none I want to show the 404 without changing the URL:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import redirect404 from './utilActions';

export function fetchVenue() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_VENUE',
            payload: axios.get('http://externalAPI.com'),
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.info(error);
            dispatch(redirect404());
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: What happened if you just remove the `404` route ? `*` should take the lead and call your `NotFound` component without changing URL

Comment: That doesn't work with any routes that have params like this one 
`<Route path="venues/:venueName" component={VenueContainer} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `replace` instead of `push`

> - push - Pushes a new location to history, becoming the current location
> - replace - Replaces the current location in history.

[react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux)

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

export default function redirect404() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(replace('/404'));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/404` route entirely and don't redirect. Right now you user is redirected to `/404` every time you cannot match the route. Your `*` path works fine as a catch all.

Comment: Unfortunately the `*` path doesn't catch routes with params :/